# What are rules in casting primitive types in expressions in Java?

Tags: java, casting, primitive-types, jshell

I'm trying to figure out why some castings work and why others do not. Can you explain to me why some of these examples work and others don't?

**Setup:**

I'm using jshell.

```
byte one = 1;
one ==> 1
```

**Example 1:**

```
jshell> byte val = 200 - 200;
val ==> 0
```

According to my knowledge these literals are of type int, but code compiles because the result fits in the byte.

**Example 2**

```
jshell> byte val = 1 - one;
|  Error:
|  incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
|  byte val = 1 - one;
|             ^-----^
```

When I'm switching one literal to a variable, code suddenly does not compile. Casting any or all of components of the espression doesn't fix the problem.

**Example 3**

```
jshell> byte val = (byte)(1) - one;
|  Error:
|  incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
|  byte val = (byte)(1) - one;
|
```

I expected this to work. After all I did convert the integer in this expression to byte, so there shouldn't be 'incompatible types' error.

**Example 4**

```
jshell> byte val = 1 - (byte)(one);
|  Error:
|  incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
|  byte val = 1 - (byte)(one);
|             ^-------------^
```

This was more an experiment to see if this would fix the problem. I didn't expect this to work.

**Example 5**

```
jshell> byte val = (byte)(1) - (byte)(one);
|  Error:
|  incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
|  byte val = (byte)(1) - (byte)(one);
|             ^---------------------^
```

This one confuses me so much. I'm casting both components to byte, so why would there be an error? After all in Example 1 there was a similar operation and Java didn't complain at all.

**Example 6**

```
jshell> byte val = (byte)(1 - one);
val ==> 0
```

In the end only casting result of the expression doesn't produce an error. Why?

Comment: Because of automatic promotion of your `byte` operands to type `int`, and the results of the `-` operations therefore being of type `int`.

Comment: You need to read the 2nd duplink to understand why `byte val = 200 - 200;` is allowed.  (And it isn't a bug in jshell.  The JLS says it is valid.)

Comment: The critical thing here is that your variable isn't `final`, thus its value is not considered a constant expression, even if you never change its value once assigned.

Answer (score 2):

Java automatically promotes each `byte`, `short`, or `char` operand to `int` when evaluating an expression. Because the operands are automatically promoted to `int` when the expression is evaluated, the result also gets promoted to `int`. Thus, the result of the expression is now of type `int`, which cannot be assigned to a `byte` without the use of a cast.

Comment: You'll need to expand a bit to explain why `byte val = 200 - 200;` is allowed.